# QSettings and "foldered", non-flat output

Tags: qt

A Registry root of an application can be a tree-like structure with "folders" and "nodes". A pFile on a mac can have inner dictionaries which are like folders. Whatever I do from QSettings is flat, even if I use a group. Is there an API that’ll let me "create a folder" that will translate in windows to a registry 'folder', and a new Dictionary on a pfile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There no publish way to do what you describe. But you can just store Qt container types like QList and QMap in QSettings. The resulting registry or plist won't be exactly what you want but it serves what you want to accomplish. Unless, of course, you want the registry or plist to be compatible with other applications than arrange their settings that way.

**Edit**

Actually, after some test, on Mac QSettings do use plist natives for standard types. You just need to put them in QVariant. For example:

```
QList<QVariant> array;
array << 1 << 2 << "3";
QMap<QString, QVariant> list;
list["one"] = 1;
list["two"] = "2";
list["3"] = array;
QSettings().setValue("somelist", list);
```

The above code produces the following plist entry:

```
<key>somelist</key>
<dict>
    <key>3</key>
    <array>
        <array>
            <integer>1</integer>
            <integer>2</integer>
            <string>3</string>
        </array>
    </array>
    <key>one</key>
    <integer>1</integer>
    <key>two</key>
    <string>2</string>
</dict>
```

So as long you convert values to QVariant, QSettings seem to try to use native types in plist. I don't know enough about Windows registry to know if it does the same there.

Comment: It seems strange to me that elements that are tree-like in their capabilities, like a pFile or a registry, QSettings won't be able to provide support for anything other than flat. I can live with flat, technically, it just... well, sucks.

Comment: Even with the "folder" facility, you still have to dig into the sub-sections yourself. It makes no difference either way to the code. You can also construct path-like keys with QSettings. Again, unless you need to exchange your preferrences/settings with other apps, I don't see the problem.

Comment: but how can I generate a "dictionary" from QSettings? Is that possible?

Comment: A QMap is like a CFDictionary, if that's what you are shooting for. To store multiple types in a QMap, use QVariant as value.

Comment: I mean, i want that my saved plist file, will HAVE new generated dictionaries because of how I use QSettings, because I ordered those new "folders" to be created there, programmatically.

Comment: If you have to have a CFDictionary as an entry in the plist from a QMap, then there's no Qt way to do it. Unless you build your own QSettings backend.

Comment: Thanks Stephen. I might do just that.